# Facebook sdk android get friends who use the same app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

So, I tried to google it, but don't have a clue why this isn't working. When i call this api:

[image]

I get this:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":683}}, error: null}
```

Now, I have 2 friends for testing purposes for this app that im doing and I need to get those friends. What am I Doing wrong?

Comment: yes, it is authorized by default. @luschn

Comment: no, it is not authorized by default. it is only "approved" by default, there is a big difference.

Comment: see this:
http://prntscr.com/d52bxr @luschn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response looks good, the only issue I can think of is that your friends did not authorize your App with the `user_friends` permission. Make sure they did.

In other words: Use the scope parameter with the `user_friends` permission in the login process.

Comment: that means the permission don´t need review (those 3 never do), but you need to authorize users with the user_friends permission.

Comment: you must have a working login already, else you would not even get that response. so ask for the user_friends permission with the scope parameter, in the login process.